# Would a network level WAN-blocked Win7 VM host be sufficiently secure with a WAN-enabled VM guest?

Tags: linux, windows-7, networking, security, virtual-machine

I have a client who is adamant about avoiding Windows 10.  For the time being, they've accepted using Windows 7 with the network interfaces disabled, but they're looking for options to continue with Internet access.

What I'm considering is setting up a Linux desktop variant as a VM guest with bridged networking and denying WAN to the MAC addresses of the host's network interfaces on the gateway.

Assuming the guest OS is patched and otherwise secured, is this a sufficiently secure way to continue using Windows 7?

Comment: You should set up the Windows 7 guest using the Host Only option to isolate it from the internet. When your client has somewhat calmed down (a) there is nothing wrong with Windows 10 and it is secure and/or (b) just adopt Linux as the client's operating system. I have been using Windows 10 for 5 years with no big issues.

Comment: @John: Windows 7 as the guest and/or Linux as the host is not feasible as this client uses CAD and other software that is either CPU-heavy or without an adequate Linux equivalent.

Comment: If you need heavy duty processing, your client should move to Windows 10 Pro as a host OS. That is the only secure way forward in your situation. It works just fine.

Comment: A Linux guest will not secure Windows 7. That angle will not work. Especially here that you want Internet for the guest machine. It is a different machine and cannot secure a host Windows 7 machine as you are trying to do

Comment: I'm not suggesting that Linux would, itself, secure the host.  The host's MAC address would be WAN blocked on the router.